# How to use field DateTime with time zone in neo4j?

Tags: php, date, neo4j

I am working with neo4j in PHP and I need to have a DateTime field that allows to store the time zone. If I save it as a string it is more difficult to make queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the timezone, and just output the string like this:

```
$x = new DateTime('2018-09-18 22:00:00', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Brussels'));
echo $x->format(DateTime::W3C);
```

Which gives you:

```
2018-09-18T22:00:00+02:00
```

When you pull your time from the DB, you can now create the object like this:

```
DateTime::createFromFormat(DateTime::W3C, $row['your_date_column']);
```

Play with it here: https://3v4l.org/DQjJO

Comment: is true, but I need to make queries such as **"Match (m: Message) where m.date> = 2018-09-18T22: 00: 00 + 02: 00 return m"**

Comment: @JaimeRoman Do you actually have use cases that require the timezone? If you just stored a numeric Unix epoch timestamp, then you can easily do time comparisons.

Comment: Yes, finally I will use Unix epoch timestamp